# Openerp 7 How to add edit/update/save without submit button to wizard

Tags: xml, python-2.7, odoo, openerp-7

I am working with stranded "Survey" and "Appraisal" modules in Openerp 7. In there there is not "**Edit**" button for middle way did surveys. It always opens a fresh copy of survey and even though you closed the survey halfway through.

[image]

How to add "Edit" or "edit"/"update"/"save without submit" button next to "Done" button or "Answer Survey" button in Openerp 7 wizard ? is it possible to do in .py file ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you dont see an "Edit" button on the wizard is because its already in edit mode. That's the mode the wizard opens in so that the user doesn't have to click an "Edit" button to enter new information like on a regular form view.

One thing I do if I want to open an existing record in a wizard is to create a button with type="object" and the name="method_name"

```
<!-- In your xml file -->
<button type="object" name="method_name" string="Button" context="{'optional': 'values'}" />
```

then have it call a method in your python file that returns an action with the following values

```
def method_name(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None): 
    # make sure to send the record id you want to open
    # it could be passed in the context, or other variable
    # i'm only using the context in this example 
    if context == None:
        context = {}

    # if the rec_int_id is False, then the wizard will try to make a new record. Otherwise, it opens the the wizard with existing data
    rec_int_id = context.get('record_id',False)

    view_id = self.pool.get('ir.ui.view').search(cr, uid, [('name','=','your name of view')])

    # search functions always returns a list, so get the 1st element if found
    if view_id:
        view_id = view_id[0]

        return {
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'view_type': 'form',
            'view_mode': 'form',
            'res_model': 'your.model.name',
            'res_id': rec_int_id, # integer id of the record to open
            'view_id': view_id, # integer view id
            'target': 'new', # opens the view as a wizard
            'context': context,
            'name': 'Any name you want to give'
        }

    else:
        raise osv.except_osv('','View not found...')
```

Comment: even though it won't open the last entered record. what should I do to make it open the last entered record to edit